# Prepare for segue with identifier JSON

Tags: json, swift, xcode, decodable

Good afternoon! I have a task, I need to do navigation (When I tap a cell, I navigate to another controller that contains the album list , then When I tap an album, I navigate to another controller that contains the list of images.
I do not know what the error is? Thank you ! My Json is http://appscorporation.ga/api-user/test

I created struct.

```
    struct ProfileElement: Decodable {
    let user: User

    let postImage: String
    let postLikes: Int
    let postTags: String
}

struct User: Decodable {
    let name, surname: String
    let profilePic: String
    let albums: [Album]
}

struct Album : Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    var images: [Image]

}
struct Image: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let url: String
}
```

I decoded by this code

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase 
    let result = try decoder.decode([ProfileElement].self, from: data)
```

I was advised to receive image data with

```
for item in result {
    for album in item.user.albums {
        for image in album.images {
            print(image)
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, I did not understand how I use data acquisition, then transfer and use them to other controllers.
Help me please.
My project in GitHub https://github.com/VladimirRebricov/TestProject

Comment: The code is not related to navigation between controllers. Please add the relevant code.

Comment: Vadian, Please tell me how to implement it. I don't know(

Comment: Vadian, thank you !

Comment: First you need to have UICollectionView or UITableView then create cells for them. Both UICollectionView or UITableView delegates have a method you can select  a row. inside that method you can do the transition. When you are done creating UICollectionView, post your code.

Comment: Search how to navigate from one ViewController to another, you will find many.